# Split a string based on "|" character in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, substring, escaping

I have a string variable in PowerShell which contains the value:

NFP|8dc3b47a-48eb-4696-abe2-48729beb63c8

I am attempting to get the beginning portion of that string into it's own variable by identifying the index of the "|" character and using a substring function to extract the first portion of the string, in this case "NFP".  I am not sure how to escape the "|" so I can use it properly.  It doesn't seem to recognize it at all.  My latest attempt is as follows:

```
    $PolicyManual = $Item["PolicyManual"] 
    write-host $PolicyManual   #Displays NFP|8dc3b47a-48eb-4696-abe2-48729beb63c8

    if ($PolicyManual.Contains([regex]::escape("|"))) {
        $PolcyManual = $PolicyManual.Substring(0, $PolicyManual.IndexOf([regex]::escape("|")))
    }
```

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't figure out how to make it work.  Can anyone offer assistance to a PowerShell novice?

Thanks.

Comment: `('NFP|8dc3b47a-48eb-4696-abe2-48729beb63c8' -split '\|')[0]`

Comment: also `('NFP|8dc3b47a-48eb-4696-abe2-48729beb63c8' -replace '\|.*')`

Comment: ... or to use your variable `($PolicyManual -split '\|')[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Olaf, I used the -split solution and it worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.contains` method doesn't know about `regex` and you are never entering the `if` condition because of this. When you do `[regex]::escape("|")`, the method is looking for a literal `\|`.

Try this instead:

```
$PolicyManual = "NFP|8dc3b47a-48eb-4696-abe2-48729beb63c8"

if ($PolicyManual.Contains('|')) {
    $element0, $element1 = $PolicyManual.Split('|')
    $element0 #=> NFP
    $element1 #=> 8dc3b47a-48eb-4696-abe2-48729beb63c8
}
```

Comment: OH WHHHHAAAAT??? Hey ghost.  Welcome back.

Comment: @Daniel it's been a while right hehe. hope you're doing great man!

Comment: Thanks, Santiago!  So, in the "Contains" method, there is really no need to escape the "|"?  Also, I am wondering what would be returned in $element0 and $element1 if there is no "|" in the string?  I will test that.

Comment: @JSteven that's correct, `contains` same as `split` methods looks for literal strings and are not `regex` compatible. If there is no `|` on the string, `element0` will return the string itself and `element1` will be `null`.